# ¿Cómo comprobar si una lista no contiene elementos repetidos? C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista:

```
List<byte> unaLista = new List<byte> { 1,4,3,6,1 };
```

¿Cómo puedo comprobar que no contenga elementos repetidos, es decir, está *Unqiue* o no?

Answer (score 5):

Usa [DISTINCT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
bool estaUnique = unaLista.Distinct().Count() == unaLista.Count();
```